# Horizontal search button alignment in firefox

Tags: css, forms, firefox, alignment

I'm stumped– I've tried everything and can't work out what's going on…

The search form at the foot of this site that I'm developing http://energybubble.net/ looks as I'd expect in Opera, Chrome and Safari, but when viewed in Firefox the search button in 1px or so higher than the search input. (I haven't done any IE testing yet, but I'll cross that bridge when I get there!)
Help!

Comment: Not sure without going through all of your code. Can you post the relevant HTML/CSS code into a JSFiddle? Is it out of the realm of possibility to detect firefox and add a pixel to the top margin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change css like this:

```
footer input {
 border: 2px solid #999;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: I can't mark your answer as correct until another 10 minutes has passed, I'm afraid. I'll pop back on in 10 mins and do it. Thanks again!